# Is there a tool for detecting browser compatibility issues in my Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, browser-support

I'm writing a Javascript library, and I'd like to be able to run it through some tool that will

1. detect any methods that are incompatible with certain browsers, and/or
2. tell me which browsers *do* support my code.

So far I can't find *anything* like this. Does it really not exist?

**Prior Research:**

- I've found http://caniuse.com for checking specific methods, but it doesn't help me identify problems I don't know about.
- I've read [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401389/test-browser-compatibility-in-an-easier-way) [after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8871955/test-browsers-compatibility-with-my-website) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3298147/whats-the-best-way-to-test-cross-browser-compatibility) about browser compatibility, but found nothing that fits.
- I've found a bunch of tools for running my unit tests in different browsers (e.g., Sauce Labs), but that's not really what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend you to use this website [http://jscc.info/ (wayback machine)](http://web.archive.org/web/20171014153820/http://jscc.info:80/) or https://seedmanc.github.io/jscc/

Its done the job for me in the past.

Comment: Looks like the domain expired.  The source is up at https://github.com/tbusser/jscc if you want to dig deep and revive it.

Comment: Hosted again by a fork here: https://seedmanc.github.io/jscc/

Answer (score 4):

You can use [eslint-plugin-compat](https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat), a plugin for the [ESlint](https://eslint.org/)  linting utility. You can even use [Browserlist](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist) to configure the browsers you want to support.

[image: Nice animation about eslint-plugin-compat]

Installation is very easy. You'll have to install eslint and this plugin:

```
npm install --save-dev eslint-plugin-compat
```

or

```
yarn add --dev eslint eslint-plugin-compat
```

And add a ESlint configuration file:

```
// .eslintrc
{
  "extends": ["plugin:compat/recommended"]
}
```

Add the supported browsers to your `package.json` file:

```
// sample configuration (package.json)
{
  // ...
  "browserslist": ["last 2 Chrome versions", "IE 11"],
}
```

And then run the linter:

```
eslint yourfile.js
```

In my case this was the output:

```
92:9   error  Promise.all() is not supported in IE 11  compat/compat
94:9   error  Promise.all() is not supported in IE 11  compat/compat
```