# Detect old Internet explorer Javascript functions ( < ES6)

Tags: javascript, backwards-compatibility, jslint, jshint, web-standards

There is a web online, library or something to detect old IE functions that are not compatible with Chrome/Firefox or just ES6?

Like: document.all, event.returnValue, etc

JsHint/Jslint are not detecting them as deprecated or incompatibles

Comment: But `document.all` is compatible with Firefox and Chrome.. It's non-standard but they've implemented it a long time ago to be compatible with IE (same with `.innerHTML` etc.)

Comment: Are you looking for https://caniuse.com/?

Comment: @slebetman They still should be considered deprecated as far as modern web development is concerned. Sure, they're included in the standard for compatibility reasons and are widely supported, but they still shouldn't be used.

Comment: Open the page in chrome; sometimes if it warns you about deprecated features, apis and may be functions used on the page.

Comment: [CanIUse.com](https://caniuse.com) is a good website for checking the compatibility of JS functions. You could also use the [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/).

Comment: @SalmanA The problem is I have a bunch of old javascript files and the owners want to migrate them to Chrome (now are currently failing for some cases), so i wanted to avoid to make a tool to check them all and maybe there was a better way out there, just to copy the script and tell me what were the problems

Comment: Just open them in Chrome, press F12 and look at all the warnings/errors.

Comment: @spunka You mention using jslint and jshint. Have you tried eslint? Also try TypeScript, it's very good at detecting deprecated properties, it'll even catch `const d = document; d.all.something`

Comment: What about using [eslint-plugin-compat](https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat)? You can use `Browserlist` to configure the browsers you want to support. For more information, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38257688/is-there-a-tool-for-detecting-browser-compatibility-issues-in-my-javascript-code/68526907#68526907).

Answer (score 1):

It's not *quite* fair to say JSLint won't tell you about deprecated properties. Let me explain.

Recall first that JavaScript is a dynamic language. You can assign any property to [almost] any object. You could assign `all` to `window` in a browser context if you wanted just by saying `window.all = "Muahahaha!!! I'm evil!!!"`. You could add `.all` to a string with...

```
var spam = "a string";
spam.all = "I'm still evil!!!"
```

Or, worse, some piece of code could have changed the prototype for `String` (or any other object type) somewhere outside of your file. Try this in a browser console:

```
String.prototype.all = String.prototype.all || "This is beyond evil.";
// 'This is beyond evil.'
var spam = "spam"
// undefined
spam.all
// 'This is beyond evil.'
```

So JSLint doesn't, by default, check for properties on objects by names. Especially for objects that could live outside of your file's context (because JSLint lints file-by-file), it simply can't know what's happened to an object's properties and identify what's valid and what isn't.

(That's what [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org) is for, btw.)

#### *Unless you tell JSLint how!!* -- the JSLint `property` directive ftw

Or you can use the [JSLint `property` directive](https://www.jslint.com/help.html#property), which does ***exactly*** what you want, if you're willing to do some work.

If you put the property directive at the top of your file, JSLint will show errors for any properties that are used by objects on the page that aren't in that list.

For instance, try this [on the official JSLint.com page](https://www.jslint.com):

```
/*property
    log
*/
/*jslint browser, devel */
function mySpam() {
    var spam = document.all;
    console.log(spam);
}
```

See how I'm using `document.all` but `all` isn't in the `property` directive? It's going to error for me.

```
1. Unregistered property name 'all'.
    var spam = document.all;
```

You might be saying, "But it will take me FOREVER to get all the **good** properties from my 3000 line file I'm linting into that directive!!"

Not so! Here's a tip: Paste your file, even unlinted, into JSLint.com. It will create a `property` directive for you in its report.

Here's one I made from [AngularJS' [sic] `route.js`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/angular/angular.js/master/src/ngRoute/route.js) in just a few seconds:

```
/*property
    $$minErr, $evalAsync, $get, angularVersion, caseInsensitiveMatch, create,
    defaultPrevented, eagerInstantiationEnabled, extend, info, isArray,
    isDefined, isObject, isUndefined, length, module, noop, originalPath,
    otherwise, preventDefault, provider, redirectTo, reload, reloadOnSearch,
    reloadOnUrl, routes, run, substr, when
*/
```

Alphabetical, even.

Now just *remove* the ones you don't want and presto! You'll catch everything you need.

Is this a little tedious, and will it take a little massaging/training on files that use `document` properly? Yes, but, again, in a dynamic language, this is close to the best you can hope for with file-by-file linters.

**NOTE:** If this doesn't solve your issue, however imperfectly, that's when we need to see more of your files and hear more precisely what problem you're trying to solve in practice.

Comment: Thanks for your time and the complete explanation! (and sorry my late reply) . I will try this option, i haven't got time yet, but it seems promising if i can make it work on a batch of files